# How can I automatically backup a file on my phone to my NAS running on my local network?

Tags: backup, sync

I have a NAS running and I can connect to it from my Linux machine (fstab):

```
 //192.168.1.4/home/backup /media/nas-backup cifs vers=1.0,username=***,password=***,auto,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

I'd like to set up an app to run on my phone and backup my photos and sms messages daily when my phone is on my network. I think I can accomplish a lot of this with Tasker. But the actually file copying, I'm not sure how to proceed. I hear Syncthing for Android is good but I can't find any documents about connecting it to to a CIFS mountable NAS.

How can I setup Syncthing (or a different program) to connect to my NAS and backup files on a regular basis?

Comment: Simply run busybox `crond`. Mounting `cifs` on Android with busybox `mount` also works.

Comment: do I need to root my phone for that?

Comment: yes. Mounting can't work without root. Also crond run by unprivileged app will be killed.